# Vista Hibernation-How does it work

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, sleep, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

I was just wondering something, I know when you go into sleep mode with vista, it writes everything to disk and powers down, and when you power up it returns it all to the RAM, but what I was wondering, does the wrote files stay on disk, or is that partition of space cleaned and empty after the power up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate mode uses the **hiberfil.sys** file to store the current RAM files of the PC. It’s managed by Windows so you can’t delete the file. I think it stays on your drive, and default usage is 75% of your RAM memory size,.

Answer (score 1):

When you enable hibernation on Windows, it creates a hidden file called hiberfil.sys in the root of the boot drive.  The file is slightly larger than the amount of RAM in your system, as it needs to be large enough to hold the contents of the systems RAM.  As long as hibernate is enabled on the system, that file will exist.  If you went to hibernate and you didnt have enough disk space, you could have the potential of losing all your data.

Comment: I understand that, maybe I should clarify the question, if you sleep, and wake, is everything from when you last slept, still stored in the hiberfil.sys

Comment: ah, you are asking about the security of the hiberfyl.sys.  You should change your question to reflect that.

Comment: I do believe much, if not all of the data will remain in hiberfil.sys.  It, as well as the pagefile, can contain sensitive information.  It is not something the casual computer user will be able to datamine, but there is some risk involved.